# Update if exists or add new element to array of objects - elegant way in javascript + lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

So I have an array of objects like that:

```
var arr = [
  {uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu"},
  {uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu"},
]
```

`uid` is unique id of the object in this array. I'm searching for the elegant way to modify the object if we have the object with the given `uid,` or add a new element, if the presented `uid` doesn't exist in the array. I imagine the function to be behave like that in js console:

```
> addOrReplace(arr, {uid: 1, name: 'changed name', description: "changed description"})
> arr
[
  {uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu"},
  {uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu"},
]
> addOrReplace(arr, {uid: 3, name: 'new element name name', description: "cocoroco"})
> arr
[
  {uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu"},
  {uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu"},
  {uid: 3, name: 'new element name name', description: "cocoroco"}
]
```

My current way doesn't seem to be very elegant and functional:

```
function addOrReplace (arr, object) {
  var index = _.findIndex(arr, {'uid' : object.uid});
  if (-1 === index) {
    arr.push(object);
  } else {
    arr[index] = object;
  }
}
```

I'm using lodash, so I was thinking of something like modified `_.union` with custom equality check.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can **use an object instead of an array**:

```
var hash = {
  '1': {uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu"},
  '2': {uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu"}
};
```

**The keys are the uids**. Now your function `addOrReplace` is simple like this:

```
function addOrReplace(hash, object) {
    hash[object.uid] = object;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

It's also possible to **use an object as an index** in addition to the array.
This way you've got **fast lookups** and also a working array:

```
var arr = [],
    arrIndex = {};

addOrReplace({uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu"});
addOrReplace({uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu"});
addOrReplace({uid: 1, name: "bli", description: "cici"});

function addOrReplace(object) {
    var index = arrIndex[object.uid];
    if(index === undefined) {
        index = arr.length;
        arrIndex[object.uid] = index;
    }
    arr[index] = object;
}
```

Take a look at the **[jsfiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ls4pf1y/)** (an object-oriented solution you'll find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rorywpxj/))

Comment: yeah, I like this structure too, but some libraries I use doesn't support it. Like [Angular typeahead](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/typeahead), which can traverse only arrays.

Comment: You can use this structure as a index only. This way you've got fast lookups and a additional array for things like a array is needed.

Comment: upvoted! there are 2 problems, i need the keys in sorted order according to timestamp and i need to be able to access all items in an array manner to compute statistical measures

Answer (score 66):

In your first approach, no need for Lodash thanks to [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
function upsert(array, element) { // (1)
  const i = array.findIndex(e => e.id === element.id);
  if (i > -1) array[i] = element; // (2)
  else array.push(element);
}
```

Example:

```
const array = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple', description: 'fruit'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Banana', description: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tomato', description: 'vegetable'}
];

upsert(array, {id: 2, name: 'Tomato', description: 'fruit'})
console.log(array);
/* =>
[
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple', description: 'fruit'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Banana', description: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tomato', description: 'fruit'}
]
*/

upsert(array, {id: 3, name: 'Cucumber', description: 'vegetable'})
console.log(array);
/* =>
[
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple', description: 'fruit'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Banana', description: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tomato', description: 'fruit'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Cucumber', description: 'vegetable'}
]
*/
```

(1) other possible names: `addOrReplace()`, `addOrUpdate()`, `appendOrUpdate()`, `insertOrUpdate()`...

(2) can also be done with `array.splice(i, 1, element)`

Note that this approach is "mutable" (vs "immutable"): it means instead of returning a new array (without touching the original array), it modifies directly the original array.

Comment: it fails for the first time

Answer (score 20):

If you do not mind about the order of the items in the end then more neat functional es6 approach would be as following:

```
function addOrReplace(arr, newObj){ 
 return [...arr.filter((obj) => obj.uid !== newObj.uid), {...newObj}];
}

// or shorter one line version 

const addOrReplace = (arr, newObj) => [...arr.filter((o) => o.uid !== newObj.uid), {...newObj}];
```

If item exist it will be excluded and then new item will be added at the end, basically it is replace, and if item is not found new object will be added at the end.

In this way you would have immutable list.
Only thing to know is that you would need to do some kind of sort in order to keep list order if you are for instance rendering list on the screen.

Hopefully, this will be handy to someone.

Comment: In my case I had to update array on array. I like your example the most so based on it here is oneliner solution if you have to merge two arrays together:
`return arr1.map(ar => [...arr2.filter(arr => ar.id !== arr.id), ...[{...ar}] ]).flat()`

Answer (score 9):

I personally do not like solutions that modify the original array/object, so this is what I did:

```
function addOrReplaceBy(arr = [], predicate, getItem) {
  const index = _.findIndex(arr, predicate);
  return index === -1
    ? [...arr, getItem()]
    : [
      ...arr.slice(0, index),
      getItem(arr[index]),
      ...arr.slice(index + 1)
    ];
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
var stuff = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4 },
];

var foo = { id: 2, foo: "bar" };
stuff = addOrReplaceBy(
  stuff,
  { id: foo.id },
  (elem) => ({
    ...elem,
    ...foo
  })
);
```

What I decided to do was to make it more flexible:

1. By using `lodash -> _.findIndex()`, the *predicate* can be multiple things
2. By passing a callback `getItem()`, you can decide whether to fully replace the item or do some modifications, as I did in my example.

**Note: this solution contains some ES6 features such as destructuring, arrow functions, among others.**

---

There is a second approach to this. We can use JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object which "holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys" plus "any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value."

```js
let myMap = new Map(
  ['1', { id: '1', first: true }] // key-value entry
  ['2', { id: '2', second: true }]
)

myMap = new Map([
  ...myMap, 
  ['1', { id: '1', first: true, other: '...' }]
  ['3', { id: '3', third: true }]
])
```

`myMap` will have the following entries in order:

```js
['1', { id: '1', first: true, other: '...' }]
['2', { id: '2', second: true }]
['3', { id: '3', third: true }]
```

We can use this characteristic of Maps to add or replace other elements:

```js
function addOrReplaceBy(array, value, key = "id") {
  return Array.from(
    new Map([
      ...array.map(item => [ item[key], item ]),
      [value[key], value]
    ]).values()
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
_.mixin({
    mergeById: function mergeById(arr, obj, idProp) {
        var index = _.findIndex(arr, function (elem) {
            // double check, since undefined === undefined
            return typeof elem[idProp] !== "undefined" && elem[idProp] === obj[idProp];
        });

        if (index > -1) {
            arr[index] = obj; 
        } else {
            arr.push(obj);
        }

        return arr;
    }
});
```

and

```
var elem = {uid: 3, name: 'new element name name', description: "cocoroco"};

_.mergeById(arr, elem, "uid");
```

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but why not use the filter function?

```
// If you find the index of an existing uid, save its index then delete it
//      --- after the filter add the new object.
function addOrReplace( argh, obj ) {
  var index = -1;
  argh.filter((el, pos) => {
    if( el.uid == obj.uid )
      delete argh[index = pos];
    return true;
  });

  // put in place, or append to list
  if( index == -1 ) 
    argh.push(obj);
  else 
    argh[index] = obj;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04vuuhgf/2/) showing how it works.

Answer (score 3):

really complicated solutions :D
Here is a one liner:

```
const newArray = array.filter(obj => obj.id !== newObj.id).concat(newObj)
```

Comment: This replaces the object with the given id if it already exists, instead of updating it.

Comment: thats true, but obviously the new object has the updated values already. But yes if you want to keep the order of the items in the array, he has to go with findindex

Comment: As I understand the question, the properties of the new object need to be merged with the properties of the old object. Some of the properties that need to be retained might not be present in the new object.

Answer (score 1):

What about having the indexes of the array same as the `uid`?, like:

```
arr = [];
arr[1] = {uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu"};
arr[2] = {uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu"};
```

that way you could just simply use

```
arr[affectedId] = changedObject;
```

Comment: will work well if I have the guarantee that uuid is always int. I think sometimes it's not the case. But even if I've had this guarantee, I feel uncomfortable to have arrays with missing elements like that: `arr[2134], arr[2135]`, when arr[0] doesn't exist.

Comment: @ganqqwerty so insted of classic array use associative one (object), this way you can use non-integer indexes and have no "holes" in your array

Answer (score 0):

`Backbone.Collection` provides exactly this functionality. Save yourself the effort when you can!

```js
var UidModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'uid'
});

var data = new Backbone.Collection([
    {uid: 1, name: "bla", description: "cucu"},
    {uid: 2, name: "smth else", description: "cucarecu"}
], {
    model: UidModel
});

data.add({uid: 1, name: 'changed name', description: "changed description"}, {merge: true});

data.add({uid: 3, name: 'new element name name', description: "cocoroco"});

console.log(data.toJSON());
```