# I want to update a value to a json object where key already exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

For example I have this following object.

```
var arr = [
     {id:1,name:"arjun"},
     {id:2,name:"kishore"}
]
```

When I push an object to an above Array, something like this

```
arr.push({id:1,name:"akash"})
```

It should update the object.

Comment: You might consider using an actual object indexed by ID instead, then it's very simple to assign to `obj[id] = 'somename'` (otherwise you'll have to use something like `.find`)

Comment: Then you will have to overload the `.push` method to update existing objects instead of just appending to the array as it does by default. `arr.push = function (obj) { /* write code here */ }`

Comment: may be you might use an object instead of an array like this. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764719/update-if-exists-or-add-new-element-to-array-of-objects-elegant-way-in-javascr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764719/update-if-exists-or-add-new-element-to-array-of-objects-elegant-way-in-javascr)

Comment: But overriding `push` is not a good idea if you are doing `push` for multiple/simple/other arrays and for multiple purposes

Comment: @Arjun I added answer. Hope it will work as per your expectations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update if exists or add new element to array of objects - elegant way in javascript + lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764719/update-if-exists-or-add-new-element-to-array-of-objects-elegant-way-in-javascr)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [{id:1,name:"arjun"},{id:2,name:"kishore"}];
arr.push = function(data){
    for(let i=0;i<this.length;i++){
      if(data.id == this[i].id){
          this[i].name = data.name;
          return this.length;
      }
    }
    this.push(data);
  return this.length;
}
arr.push({id:1,name:"akash"});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks Onk_r and Akhil .. Got what i have expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this to update the object property of an array **:**

```js
var arr = [{id:1,name:"arjun"},{id:2,name:"kishore"}];

var obj = {id:1,name:"akash"};

arr.map(item => {
    (item.id == obj.id) ? (item.name = obj.name) : ''; 
});


console.log("Modified Array", arr);
```

Comment: Rohit, I tried your solution but it doesnt work as expected. Ok, let me elaborate the problem a little bit.

I have a table having more than 30 pages, each page having 10 rows, Each row having one column that has a dropdown. I should be able to submit multiple request when i change dropdown values for each row, ON onchange event I am passing a data, and I am converting that into a json. And trying to push it.  In short, Your code only works when there are two objects in an array, not more than that.

Comment: @ArjunSarthi I did not get you