# Update an array in one line Javascript

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to minimize the code for the below operation ?

```
      const item: any; // Incoming data

      const index: number = basketModel.data.coupons.findIndex(
        (x: any) => x.couponId === item.couponId
      );
      if (index === -1) { // new item just push it
        basketModel.data.coupons.push(item);
      } else {
        if (item.count === 0) { // If current count is 0 remove the item from array
          basketModel.data.coupons.splice(index, 1);
        } else { // else update the array with new count
          basketModel.data.coupons[index] = item;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375465/952310

Comment: @YairNevet That's what i did too. Was wondering if there is a single line operation which can also do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this onliner (kinda of), but it is a bit harder to read :)

```
const item: any; // Incoming data
const index: number = basketModel.data.coupons.findIndex(
    (x: any) => x.couponId === item.couponId
);
basketModel.data.coupons.splice(
    index === -1 ? basketModel.data.coupons.length : index
  , index === -1 ? 0 : 1 
  , ... ((index > -1 && item.count === 0) ? [] : [item]));
```